# Revert master for origin

Tags: git

Tag 1.2.3 had changes merged onto it from which tag 1.2.4 was created and released.

The merge accidentally overwrote a lot of code that shouldn't have been overwritten.

How do I completely reset master at origin to tag 1.2.3 so that all of the changes in 1.2.4 are completely overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you `merge --no-ff`. If yes, just revert that commit. I mean. Go into 1.2.4 and revert the commit. Then you must `push --force` both branches and tags. I think `1.2.3` does not need any push or modification. But the damaged `1.2.4` yes. You need:

1. `git checkout overwrittenbranch`
2. `git revert HEAD` to remove last commit
3. `git tag 1.2.4` to fix tag position
4. `git push origin 1.2.4 --force` force because you need to overwrite tag and/or branches